Does の代わりに means "Do it for me" or "instead of me"?

The characters are discussing going to a group date  (合コン) with some girls. However some of them can't come...  So one character tells him "it's so sudden so sorry I can't come"
Then another? tells him this. Does he mean "find a girlfriend instead of me?" or "find a gf for me"?

It can grammatically mean both, but here, I think it means “find a girlfriend (for your own sake) instead of me (finding a girlfriend for my own sake)” just based on common sense.
Note that the absence of くれる does not prevent your latter interpretation. And interestingly, even the presence of くれる（i.e. 俺の代わりに彼女見つけてきてくれよ）does not exclude the former interpretation either.
